# distributed lag non-linear models, DLNM r package

Tags: generalized-linear-model, biostatistics, poisson-regression, generalized-additive-model, relative-risk

I am new to statistics and a beginner in DLNM. I am trying to understand the different functions of DLNM.

In the 'crosspred' of DLNM, the exponentiated regression coefficient from the Poisson models, exp(fit), is the relative risk/rate ratio (RR), while with GAM, exp(fit) is at the original scale of the response variable.